# Subclassing both sides of association relationship

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I face this type of design question now and then but I haven't found a general way to solve it. Here are the details:

I have a `Table` class which has `Grid` instances for row header, column header and the table itself. Both classes are meant to be reusable components.

```
class Grid {
    public void Bar() { /* ... */}
}

class Table {
    public Grid[] Grids { get; }
    public void Foo() { /* ... */ }
}
```

I also have a `CustomGrid` that adds a new method (drawing fancy colours with some logic). Now I would like subclass Table to add methods that expose the new features coming with `CustomGrid`.

```
class CustomGrid : Grid {
    public void Bar2() { /* ... */}
}

class CustomTable : Table {
    public void Foo2() { /* ... */ }
}
```

- However, since the `Table` has references to `Grid` objects, `CustomTable` needs to downcast them `CustomGrid` to use the new methods, which I think is not very pretty.
- By using generics in `Table` class, `CustomTable` can use `CustomGrid`s, but I think type-checking and downcasting will still be necessary.
- I would like to use composition over inheritance but it will prevent overriding `OnPaint` method. Also, some private constructs will need to be made public for use in containing class.

How would you approach this design? I suppose the difficulties above imply a problem in it, but please point out any mistakes in the evaluation of options as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `new` keyword:

```
public class CustomTable : Table
{
    new public CustomGrid[] Grids { get; }
    public void Foo2() { /* ... */ }
}
```

This will override your `Grid[] Grids { get; }` to `CustomGrid[] Grids { get; }`

Comment: Thanks. However, this will cause two separate arrays to be allocated in Table and CustomTable class.